# Issue with website CSS animation flashing

Tags: html, css

So i have been developing a loading screen website for a gaming community in a game called MVG and for some reason i have an issue with the site where after the first fade out of the image it flashes and it then does this for every image im unable to see what the problems is i would really like some help since otherwise the website is finished for me thanks in advance.

here is my first draft of the website https://mynamejack.hxane.com/MVGCWloadingscreen/

just click inspect elements and you should be able to view all the code but i will post it below anyway

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>MVG loading screen</title>
   <link href="assets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="outer">
           <div class="details">
               <img alt="MVG" src="assets/images/logo/mvg-logo.png" style="opacity: 100%;">
               <style>
                       img {             
                         display: block;
                         margin-left: auto;
                         margin-right: auto;
                         margin-top: 580px;
                       }
               </style>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
body {                                   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: arial;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    animation: animate 60s ease-in-out infinite;
    background-size: cover;
}
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
.details {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
@keyframes animate {         /* When you want to change the image put the image name in replacethis.jpg and make sure its a jpg also make sure the % adds up to 100% otherwise it spazes out 
                             If the slideshow brakes please let me know on discord MyNameJack#6969 or if you know css you can fix it */
    0%, 100% {
        background-image: url(images/slideshow/replacethis.jpg);
    }
    11% {
        background-image: url(images/slideshow/replacethis.jpg);
    }
    22% {
        background-image: url(images/slideshow/replacethis.jpg);
    }
    33% {
        background-image: url(images/slideshow/replacethis.jpg);
    }
    44% {
        background-image: url(images/slideshow/replacethis.jpg);
    }
    55% {
        background-image: url(images/slideshow/replacethis.jpg);
    }
    66% {
        background-image: url(images/slideshow/replacethis.jpg);
    }
    77% {
        background-image: url(images/slideshow/replacethis.jpg);
    }
    88% {
        background-image: url(images/slideshow/replacethis.jpg);
    }
    99% {
        background-image: url(images/slideshow/replacethis.jpg);
    }
    100% {
        background-image: url(images/slideshow/replacethis.jpg);
    }
}
```

Comment: i edited your css and speed the whole thing up to 5s, the loaded all animations by clicking the lines in de devtools.. after activating them all, only the one at 99% made a short flash, but the rest was ok..

Comment: ok thanks im assuming now that the key frame has to be a proper % like 10% 20% not 90 % too 99% thanks dude ill have a look at it